# "DLL load failed" trying to import cv (from OpenCV-python)

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to execute `import cv`, the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed it using `pip install OpenCV-python` also tried by installing from sourceforge.net *(recent one)* later copied **cv2.pyd** from `build\python\x64` and pasted it in `python 36\Lib\site-packages`. I work on windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Would you please give the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: import cv2 is code which I am executing

Comment: do you have 2 versions of python (i.e. 2.7 and 3.6) it could be that you installed opencv in another version?  try using pip3 install instead to make sure it is installed version 3.6

Comment: No I have only 3.6 I tried it still error persists

Comment: try import cv2, should work

Comment: I used pip install OpenCV-python and pip3 install OpenCV-python later in idle typed import cv2 it shows same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means your Python environment is unable to find the OpenCV module. You need to tell Python where to find it. Just to make things easier, use python 2 to run your script (python instead of python3) and try python 3 after python 2 works.

1. (Optional) Restart the system, just in case your system hasn't updated environment variables. Windows needs this.
2. Find the directory where you installed OpenCV. If you have multiple installations, please uninstall everything and install only 1, and make sure you take note of the installation directory.
3. Go to that installation directory, and in the subdirectory that contains the built files, search for the python module. It might look similar to this: C:\opencv\build\python\3.4.1 but it changes depending on your installation method.
4. We need to set an environment variable. Usually you go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System and then click on the "Advanced system settings" link, then click on the "Environment variables" button near the bottom of the menu. This might change depending on your Windows version, but you can easily google this.
5. Look for a variable called PYTHONPATH. If you have it we'll append something to it, otherwise click the "New.." button under System for all users or User variables (for your account only) and for "Variable name" enter: "PYTHONPATH".
6. Set the "Variable value" to the path you found in (2). If appending to an existing variable, make sure paths are separated by ;
7. Restart the system. import cv should work now.

Comment: One can log out and back in to get Windows environment variables refreshed without a full restart.

Comment: Still it persistsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found